# How can i upload file to a specific folder in google drive -Google drive API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How can i upload file to a specific folder in google drive  -Google drive API? 
I have this code, and it upload my file to the main folder in google drive.

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    $file->setTitle($file_name);
    $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
    $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
    $service->files->insert($file, array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
         'mimeType' => $mime_type
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hi, you have to set the `parents` property with an array of parent folder IDs (see list of property here, for a file creation, https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in V3. It's called "setting a parent" since once the file is inside the folder it will also inherit the sharing options of the parent it's in.

Below 2 lines will set the name of the file and then **setParents** will define what folder you want to put the file in. Parameter is an array but don't put more than 1 item or you'll get an error:

```
$file->setName("world");
$file->setParents(['SOME_UNIQUE_FOLDER_ID']);
```